# Quickly restart node server

Tags: node.js, httpserver

I'm using node.js to host a project I'm working on on my local machine using 'http-server'.

Currently if I want to see a change I made to the the Javascript or HTML files, I have to press Ctrl+C stop the server, close my web browser, then restart the server, then reopen my browser and navigate to the hosted site again. Is there a way I can automate this so that there is less manual work? I'm using Visual Studio Code for development.

Thanks

Comment: You can use [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon)

Comment: This seems like exactly what I needed, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in the commentary mentioned **Nodemon** is what you are looking for.

### Solution

#### Install Nodemon

```
npm install nodemon -g
```

- the flag - g will install nodemon globally in your system path so you can use it for all of your projects

#### Start Project

```
nodemon index.js
```